# Uploading large number of blobs to Azure storage causes Host thresholds exceeded: [Connections] exception

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have .Net Core 3.1 Azure Function (V3). I need to upload large number (~5000) of small blobs (~100kb) to azure storage. I found example on how to achieve this [in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-upload-files?tabs=dotnet).

I have slightly modified example to fit my needs and end up with this code:

```
public async Task BulkInsert(List<BlobData> data)
{
    var uploadOptions = new BlobUploadOptions
    {
        TransferOptions = new StorageTransferOptions
        {
            // Maximum number of workers in a parallel transfer.
            MaximumConcurrency = 8,
            // Maximum length of a transfer: 50MB.
            MaximumTransferSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024
        }
    };

    var tasks= blobData.Select(bd => UploadBlob(bd, uploadOptions));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}


private async Task UploadBlob(BlobData blobData, BlobUploadOptions options)
{
    var blobClient = _blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blobData.CreateBlobName());

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blobData))))
    {
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(ms, options);
    }
}
```

But when I am uploading blobs I am recieving following exception:

`Host thresholds exceeded: [Connections]. For more information, see https://aka.ms/functions-thresholds.`

If I check azure metrics I can see that azure function has reached connection limit (currencly it's 600)[image: function_connections]

So I think that creating `BlobClient` creates a new connection and does not reuse it.

- I cannot re-use `BlobClient` since I need unique name for each blob.
- I do not want to run this in sync since i think that it would significally increase the upload time
- I tried to upload in a chunks of 8 objects, but result is still the same. (maybe connections are still open in whole duration of this method)
- I could increase blob size and have less blobs overall, but I think that it's not scalable solution.

Is there a better way to upload large number of blobs into Azure Storage without hitting connection limit?